# log when a managedbean is initialized

Tags: eclipse, logging, managed-bean, jsf-2.2, myfaces

In the past, when I started with Eclipse Juno and MyFaces 2.1.x, when I had managed beans, and was debugging the application in tomcat 7.0, I would see the managed beans being created in the console log.

Now I have switched to Eclipse Kepler, and MyFaces 2.2, and I no longer see the log entries in the console for managed beans.

I have searched everywhere, but stackoverflow keeps returning search results for login, logged, etc when I search for logging.

How do I log when a managed bean instance is created in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the `com.sun.faces.mgbean`package for logging statements. The classes have an internal logging logic which results in `messages` which are `String`s. But as far as I could tell these messages only get created when an error occured, not when a bean gets created. To be sure, try to change your logging frame works log level to `trace`.

Maybe you have your own logging statement within your beans? Does it look like something like this?

```
private void init() {
  log.debug(getClass().getName() + " created!");
}
```